# The complexity of the leading fractional bit of a power of a rational number

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, na.numerical-analysis, computable-analysis

On a mailing list (math-fun) that I subscribe to Dan Asimov asked what's the most efficient way to calculate the leading decimal digits (say 10 of them) of $(p/q)^n \bmod 1$ where $p$ and $q$ are fixed (think of $p/q = 3/2$) and $n$ varies.  There were a number of suggestions, but all of them clearly had complexity proportional to $n$.  So my question is, for concreteness, let $b(n) = \lfloor 2(3/2)^n \rfloor \bmod 2$ (the leading fractional bit of $(3/2)^n$).  Suppose that $n$ is specified in binary.  What is the complexity (both time and space) of calculating the function $b(n)$?  After thinking about it for a while I wouldn't be surprised if it's exp-space hard.  Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: You may want to change that title: when I read the question on the home page, the first thing I thought is "what's the problem, the leading bit is always 1..."

Comment: @Federico, good point.  I added "fractional" before bit.

Answer (score 4):

From the review of 
Mika Hirvensalo, Juhani Karhumäki, and Alexander Rabinovich, Computing partial information out of intractable: powers of algebraic numbers as an example,  J. Number Theory 130 (2010), no. 2, 232–253, MR2564895 (2010j:11117), it looks like there may be something of interest there.

Comment: A link to the paper: http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rabinoa/pub/power-algebraic.pdf